# Where to write a diary in Chinese?

Tags: writing, learning

Practicing Chinese is hard when you are not following regular lectures or if you do not know anyone with who talk.

Beyond practicing everyday following a book or an app, I would like to write regularly something on my own, like a mini-blog or a Tweeter. This would keep motivation flowing from the fact that other people can read you, and learning from the words and syntax rules you need to check each time.

However, is there a typical place where to do so, where competent people can read and correct you?

Comment: I think you can try [豆瓣网](https://www.douban.com/) or [小记](https://apps.apple.com/us/app/%E5%B0%8F%E8%AE%B0/id975031499), they are far from best choices but my humble suggestions.

Answer (score 2):

If you are interested in writing AND having native speakers correct what you write, then you should definitely try out [lang-8.com](http://lang-8.com/). The website allows you to do exactly that.

Technically it's not a (micro-)blogging platform, but if your goal is to improve your Chinese, that might be a reasonable compromise. And nobody will stop you from writing diary-like posts if you like.

Answer (score 1):

I am chinese in chengdu. All chinese love write min-blog in weibo or weichat. These app like Twitter or facebook in your live. You can download this free app in google or apple  appstore. If you have any question, please let me know.

Answer (score 1):

I strongly recommend you use WeChat or Weibo. Weibo is a micro-blogger and WeChat is Chinese WhatsApp. Italki is also a good choice, there are some language exchanger can correct your dairies everyday.